# Binding generic service with its implementation and subtypes

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice

Disclaimer: Bear with me for a good amount of code to explain the scenario.

In one of the maven modules (core), we have the following classes:

```
abstract class ReportingEvent {
}

abstract class Element {

    public <E extends ReportingEvent> Optional<E> getReportEvent() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

services such as:

```
public interface Reporting<E extends ReportingEvent> {
    void report(E event);
}

interface InternalService {
}

public class InternalServiceImpl implements InternalService {

    @Inject
    Reporting<ReportingEvent> reporting; // 1. Possible to use a generic type? How?

    private void reportEvents(BatchRequest batchRequest) {
        batchRequest.stream()
                // section below is of importance
                .map(m -> m.getEntity().getReportEvent()) // the generic method from 'Element'
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .forEach(event -> reporting.report(event)); // method from 'Reporting'
    }
}

class CoreBindingModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(InternalService.class).to(InternalServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

---

Further in another maven module(consumer) that we deploy, we have classes related to and implementing the above as:

```
abstract class BaseReporting extends ReportingEvent {
}

class ColdReporting extends BaseReporting {
}

abstract class Node extends Element {
}

class Cold extends Node {
    @Override
    public Optional<ColdReporting> getReportEvent() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(new ColdReporting()); // some business logic
    }
}

class ReportingImpl implements Reporting<ReportingEvent> { // 2. Use 'BaseReporting' here
    void report(ReportingEvent event){}
}

class ConsumerBindingModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<Reporting<ReportingEvent>>() {}).to(ReportingImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

---

The above code works fine. But the problem is the use of types that don't quite relate to the modules.

<sup>A...</sup> So if I change the binding in the consumer module to

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Reporting<BaseReporting>>() {}).to(ReportingImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

with

```
class ReportingImpl implements Reporting<BaseReporting> {
    void report(BaseReporting event){}
}
```

I get an error

> ```
> No implementation for Reporting<ReportEvent> was bound.
> while locating Reporting<ReportEvent> for field at InternalServiceImpl.reporting(InternalServiceImpl.java:21)
> ```

which is relevant and I cannot make use of `Reporting<BaseReporting>` in the core module anyway.

<sup>B...</sup> On the other hand if I try to inject `Reporting` as:

```
@Inject
Reporting<? extends ReportingEvent> reporting;
```

then IDEA states

> ```
>  Required type: capture of ? 
>  Provided: ReportingEvent
> ```

on the line

```
...forEach(event -> reporting.report(event))
```

Is there a way to get around this situation while trying to solve for <sup>1</sup> and <sup>2</sup> as mentioned in the code sections?

Comment: What does the return type of `m.getEntity()` look like?

Comment: @user7 `Element` detailed as `abstract class Element ` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

(I might be restating what you already know for the most part)

Keeping aside your Guice related modules and configuration, your problem can be written down as

```
Reporting<ReportingEvent> reportingEvent = new ReportingImpl();
Reporting<? extends ReportingEvent> reporting = baseReporting;
reporting.report(reportingEvent); //won't work
```

which is identical to

```
List<? extends String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a"); //won't work
```

---

Say, you have a `HotReporting` class that extends `BaseReporting`, thus you have something like this

```
public class ReportingImpl implements Reporting<ReportingEvent> { 
    public void report(ReportingEvent event){}
}
public class ColdReportingImpl implements Reporting<ColdReporting> { 
    public void report(ColdReporting event){}
}

public class HotReportingImpl implements Reporting<HotReporting> { 
    public void report(HotReporting event){}
}
```

Assume if you injected a `HotReportingImpl` for the field `Reporting<? extends ReportingEvent> reporting`.

In your code what if `m.getEntity().getReportEvent()` returns a `ColdReporting`? It is not compatible with what the `report` method expects here (a `HotReporting`).

---

**Option 1:**

I would try to get rid of the generic type parameters and define `Reporting` as

```
public interface Reporting {
    void report(ReportingEvent event);
}

public class BaseReportingImpl implements Reporting {
    @Override
    public void report(ReportingEvent event) {

    }
}
//... and so on
```

**Problems:**

- If you relied on the exact subtype of a `ReportingEvent` in the implementation (need typecasts which is not good).
- Still, a `HotReportingImpl` can get a `ColdReporting` object as an argument.

**Option 2:**

You can make the `InternalService` *generic* by adding the type parameters to it.

---

If the classes implementing `Reporting` have to deal with concrete types of `ReportingEvent`, then it doesn't seem right for `Element` to return the base type (`ReportingEvent`).

Have a look at [Typesafe heterogeneous containers by Joshua Bloch](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8). Your problem overlaps with that. You can maintain a mapping from the type of `ReportingEvent` to the corresponding subclass of `Reporting` with that type argument.